# How to use system.web.dll in .Net 3.5 version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like to use the below code in .Net version 3.5. but i am not able to find system.web dll for .Net 3.5

```
public System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit Height { get; set; }

TopLayout.Height = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit(110, UnitType.Percentage);
```

anybody have solution to use the above code in 3.5

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Web v2.0.0.0. This is the version appropriate for .NET 3.5

Be aware that .NET versions 2 → 3.5 are completely compatible - basically, 3 and 3.5 just added more libraries to 2.

Answer (score 0):

The Unit structure has been present in all versions since .net 1.1 (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

You're almost certainly missing a reference to `System.Web`.

v2.0 is appropriate here since 3.5 is a superset of the framework built on top of 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you've got your project set to target the "client profile" only if you can't add a reference to System.Web.

Right click on your project and select properties. In the screen that appears make sure that you are targeting the full version of the framework and not the client profile.